# PHP: How to initialize cells in a 2D array with all existing keys, so that all rows have the same number of elements

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

Given this example array, with dynamic keys (not known in advance) :

```
[
  ["blep" => 32, "blip" => 42],
  ["blap" => 99, "blep" => null],
  ["lel" => "hulo"]
]
```

I would like to be able to get this output :

```
[
  ["blap" => null, "blep" => 32, "blip" => 42,  "lel" => null],
  ["blap" => 99, "blep" => null, "blip" => null, "lel" => null],
  ["blap" => null, "blep" => null, "blip" => null, "lel" => "hulo"]
]
```

How would I achieve that? Should I just loop over the array elements to get all the keys that exist, then re-loop over those elements to declare the keys that are not declared in the element? Is there no better way?

Thank you !

Comment: No, there's no better way then you described. You need to know all keys before adding.

Comment: You could use collection methods. map() and merge() will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
    $collection = collect([
        ["blep" => 32, "blip" => 42],
        ["lel" => "hulo"]
    ]);


    $existsKeys = collect(['blap'=>null, 'blep'=>null, 'blip'=>null, 'lel'=>null]);
    $newCollection = $collection->map(function($item, $key) use ($existsKeys) {
        $diff = $existsKeys->diffKeys($item);
        return collect($item)->merge($diff);
    });

    dd( $newCollection );
```

For more information please take a look on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods).

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question because I didn't state that the keys in my arrays are dynamic. I guess I should just iterate over the array to get all the keys that exists and then use your solution?

Comment: @MartinVandersteen, if you have dynamic keys then just pass that on the ```$existsKeys = collect($dynamic_keys);``` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array=[
    ["blep" => 32, "blip" => 42],
    ["blap" => 99, "blep" => null],
    ["lel" => "hulo"]
];

$counter=0;
foreach($array as $data){
    isset($data['blep'])?true:$array[$counter]['blep']=null;
    isset($data['blip'])?true:$array[$counter]['blip']=null;
    isset($data['blap'])?true:$array[$counter]['blap']=null;
    isset($data['lel'])?true:$array[$counter]['lel']=null;
    $counter++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

This code will go through your array and if it finds a value already set will keep it else will add a new array field with the value null. At the end of the loop all the nested array will have the same fields.

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [blep] => 32
            [blip] => 42
            [blap] => 
            [lel] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [blap] => 99
            [blep] => 
            [blip] => 
            [lel] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lel] => hulo
            [blep] => 
            [blip] => 
            [blap] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: And if keys are dynamic?

Comment: This was not mentioned in the question so i assumed that they will be static otherwise it will be mentioned. I mean if the keys are dynamically set then we will need a whole new array to construct and not just "modify" the existing one.

Comment: Indeed the keys are dynamic. I will update my question sorry for the incompleteness